# OnListItemClick event is not working when I use checkbox in list_item.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, checkbox

My code is working fine, but when I use checkbox in my `list_item.xml`, the `OnListItemClick` and the `startActivity(intent)` don't work. I want to use checkbox to select multiple apps, and do some action using button like some toast or something.

My `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private AppAdapter listadapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

    try{
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

        if(intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {

    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> appList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

    for(ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try{
             if(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                appList.add(info);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return appList;
}

 private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

        listadapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, applist);

        return null;
    }
 }
```

Adapter.java

```
public class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo>{
private List<ApplicationInfo> appList = null;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;

public AppAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                  List<ApplicationInfo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.appList = objects;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((null != appList) ? appList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != appList) ? appList.get(position) : null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if(null == view) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    ApplicationInfo data = appList.get(position);

    if(null != data) {
        TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        packageName.setText(data.packageName);
        iconView.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
    }
    return view;
 }
 }
```

list_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_package"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<CheckBox           
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="end|right" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So many things to correct in the way you are asking this question. What do you mean it doesn't work? Does it crash? Just not show? Clarify! Also shorten your code. No one wants to pick through 300 lines of dumped code. Shorten it to specifically where you are having the issue.

Comment: Without placing checbox in xml when i click on list item then app at that position starts when after using checkbix in my layout when i click on list item nothing happens

Comment: If it helps someone, i managed to solve it by setting android:focusable="false" in the checkbox component